# Integration on an infinitesimal interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the following problem.

Let f(x,y) regular enough, and consider
\begin{equation}
u(x)=\int_{\xi}^{\xi + d\xi}f(x,y)dy
\end{equation}
The book that I'm studying says $u(x)= f(x,\xi)d\xi$. Why this?

Comment: Hint: consider $g(z)=\int_\xi^{\xi+z}f(x,y)dy$. What is the derivative of $g$ at $0$?

Comment: @Wojowu the limits are the $y$ variable, the $x$ variable is little better than a parameter.

Comment: Please give the book and its approach to calculus. On its face the statement is wrong. It could be right if $\simeq$ or $\approx$ were used in the last equation instead of $=$.

Comment: @LutzL the book is "A second course in stochastic process", Karlin,Taylor. And the question can be found in page 198. (it consider the integral before in $[\xi, \xi + \Delta)$ and then shrinking $\Delta$ to $d\xi$ it states the upper assertion

Comment: Then it is only correct with the equality sign if $f$ is a left-continuous step function in $y$ that is constant in the interval. Since the Ito integral is designed that way, this is somewhere in the justifications/definitions stage of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ignore the argument $x$ for a moment.

$$\int_\xi^{\xi+d\xi}f(y)dy=\left.F(y)\right|_\xi^{\xi+d\xi}=F(\xi+d\xi)-F(\xi)=F'(\xi){d\xi}=f(\xi)d\xi,$$ where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$.

Now reintroducing the argument $x$ doesn't change the result, as there is no derivativation/integration with respect to it.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{\xi}^{\xi + d\xi}f(x,y)dy$ is the area under the curve $f(x,y)$ from $y=\xi$ to $y=\xi+d\xi$. Now since $d\xi$ is infinitesimal we can take the hight to be constant equal to $f(x,\xi)$ the width is of course $d\xi$ so the area is $f(x,\xi)d\xi$. This is probably the best way to understand it.